# cdecl clarification required: what is an "array 5?"

Tags: c++, arrays, cdecl

Go here: http://cdecl.org/

Input:

```
char (*arr)[5]
```

Output:

> declare arr as pointer to array 5 of char

What is an "array 5"? Does this simply mean an array with 5 elements?

Comment: Yes, it does. What makes you uncomfortable with that? The fact that arrays can decay into pointers?

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez  An array can implicitly cast to a pointer, which points to the first element, however this 'decay' is not a pointer to an array. What the OP has is an actual pointer to an array

Comment: no discomfort, just clarification needed

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, ah, I see how to make the output be a different color now using the > symbol! I had no idea. Where is this magical list of stackoverflow symbology? Also, I find it amusing that we have almost the same reputation points. :) If you just multiply yours by 2 to be as big as mine when multiplied by 1000, they'd be equal.

Comment: @GabrielStaples  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: @GabrielStaples: indenting text by 4 chars is used for code formatting. `>` is for quoting text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pointer to an array of 5 elements.

```
//Standard array
char array[5];

//pointer to array
char (*arr)[5];

//Assign pointer of array to arr
arr = &array;

//Dereference arr and use it.
(*arr)[1] = 4;
```

Pointers and references to arrays are useful for passing arrays to functions, as well as returning them. Do not return local non-static arrays though as their life time ends on return.

To reference an array you can use this declaration:
`char (&arr)[5] = array;`

Comment: I can't accept your answer for 10 more minutes apparently. Gotta give other people a chance too.